# How use background color not equals to colorPrimary

Tags: android

In my android project

```
 <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                    android:id="@+id/viewJsonButton"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:onClick="@{() -> handler.onClickViewJson(item)}"
                    android:text="@string/view_json"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

As result button's background is equal to **colorPrimary**

Nice. It's work fine.

But I need to change background color of button - not equal of **colorPrimary**.

this not help:

```
android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
```

Comment: Did you try to sen bacground as color, e.g: `android:background="#F0F"`?

Comment: Yes, but it not help. Not change background's color.

Comment: Did you check `Theme Attribute Mapping`? Here you heve `Filled button` or `Outlined button`:   https://material.io/develop/android/components/material-button/

Answer (score 0):

[screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hr3mh.png)
[screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FecY.png)

android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light" works fine in Android Studio.

Comment: In com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton not work

Comment: I use :   android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light" in com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton. But it NOT help. The background color is equal to "colorAccent" from styles.xml